# SharePoint Installation Problem on Windows Server 2008

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, internet-explorer-8, windows-server-2008

I have installed MOSS 2007 on Windows Server 2008.

I am facing a strange problem:

1. I am unable to logon to SharePoint using IE 8, but am able to using Firefox. Pl note that I have taken care of the security in IE.
2. After creating a web application, when I try to chage the web application for creating a Site collection..I am unable to change it (even if I select the web application it says "No Selection".
3. I am unable to add web parts to any of the sites created! ( Pl note that I have created the sites by using a workaround..changing the SiteId=null to site Id = Id of the Site using SharePoint Manager)

I find no entries in the logs or no error messages..

Please help me in this regard.

Grace

Comment: I'm assuming you are explicitly prefixing your username in the prompt with the domain name?  What rights does this account have on the server and within the farm?

Comment: The user has full control of the web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 on Windows Server 2008 is much more stringent with its default security settings. Even disabling IE Enhanced Security Configuration does not allow all functionality. This is to discourage you from logging into the server and perhaps inadvertantly installing an IE addon that compromises security.

You really should connect to SharePoint Central Administration from your local machine. Then you won't have the security problems and also will be following Microsoft best practice.

Comment: Hi Alex,

Thank you for answering to my problem.

I tried as you suggested. However am facing the same problem in the local machine. It has Windows Vista. 

Any guesses?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the Site (Central Admin ) to the Trusted Site in IE and Make the Security Setting as Low. It will give all the Required stuffs like Javascript and it should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to disable the loop back checking if the site is using a host header name. See [this article for more details](http://blog.brianfarnhill.com/2008/11/ie8-beta-2-authentication-issues-with-host-header-configured-sites/).

Answer (score 0):

I have also had the same problem, not being able to select a web application. In our case we ended up reinstalling sharepoint (actually a clean install of the OS), then it worked fine.

There was probably some step in the installation that we did not do in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Sharepoint on Windows Server 2008 is not a regular install. Make sure you have the latest Cumulative update installed + SP2. Better yet, slipstream the installation. 
Take note, especially when installing Language Packs attention is need when performing the install, there is a specific order in which to install the product / updates / packs.

More info [Code eater blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/wael/archive/2008/12/03/sharepoint-2007-with-language-packs-on-windows-server-2008.aspx)